# VB application with Crystal report 9

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

We have a VB6 application using CR 7. We want to move the VB application to another box where CR 9 is available. Should I rebuild VB apps with CR 9? Any suggessions?

---

We deployed copied the application to new box with CR10. But we are getting "component 'crystl32.ocx' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid". We missed to install CR runtime?

Comment: Does it run without rebuilding? I mean why you just don't try out?

Comment: As Arvo said, **If it's not broken, don't fix it**! In other words, if it runs in the new version as-is, then there's no need to rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old v7 app will run just fine on the v9 box, but you MUST install your v7 runtimes. Prior to v9, all Crystal runtime files went into the "System32" directory. Beginning with v9, the runtimes started going into Program Files / Common Files directories (the exact directory changes for each version). This allows for multiple versions to be supported on the same machine. The Crystal OCX file you referenced needs to be installed by your old app.

And just to be clear, your old v7 Crystal app will not automatically work with v9, v10, etc Crystal installed. Crystal runtimes only work with the version designed for.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there was a big API change from version 8 to version 9, so I doubt that your application will run out of the box with CR 9. In either case I would rebuild the application, just to make sure it doesn't break already on compile time.